# Passing a path to BASH script with a variable

Tags: bash, macos

I've written a little script that uses the `hdiutil` in OSX but I'm having an issue when passing a path to the output variable where the path contains spaces. The path is generated simply by the user dragging the path folder onto the terminal window and then reading that to a variable. Basically I have for the path:

```
echo "Drag Destination Folder to Window or Leave Blank to Create on Desktop:"
read createDest
createDest=$(echo "$createDest" | sed 's/ /\\ /g')
```

I then prompt for the desired name with

```
echo "Enter Name for Image (also used for Volume):"
read varName
varName=$(sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g' <<< $varName) #remove illegal chars
```

Combine them with 
`path=$(echo ${createDest}/${varName})`

And finally generate the file with

```
Echo -n $varPass | hdiutil create -encryption -stdinpass -type SPARSEBUNDLE -size ${varSize}G -fs HFS+J -volname $varName $path
```

This all works fine as long as there are no spaces in the path but as soon as there are I get an error from `hdiutil` stating:

```
hdiutil: create: Only one image can be created at a time.
```

If I type the pass in manually its fine so I'm a bit confused as to where my formatting has gone wrong.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Cheers

Chris

Comment: You do not want to manually escape the spaces in your path; the backslashes you are adding are *literal data*, not protecting spaces in the value of `createDest`. Quoting the expansion is sufficient.

Comment: Perfect. That got it. Thanks chepner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is quote the parameter expansions; that is sufficient to protect the whitespace. Adding backslashes manually simply creates a value that does not represent an existing path.

```
echo "Drag Destination Folder to Window or Leave Blank to Create on Desktop:"
read createDest

echo "Enter Name for Image (also used for Volume):"
read varName
varName=${varName//[^[:alnum:]._-]/_}  # more efficient than running sed

printf '%s' "$varPass" | hdiutil create -encryption -stdinpass -type SPARSEBUNDLE -size "${varSize}G" -fs HFS+J -volname "$varName" "$path"
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote all variables everywhere:

```
echo -n "$varPass" | hdiutil create -encryption -stdinpass -type SPARSEBUNDLE -size "${varSize}G" -fs HFS+J -volname "$varName" "$path"
```

Comment: Hmm. Tried that but it just throws an error saying `hdiutil: create failed - No such file or directory`

Comment: Good! That means that we solved your problem and now you have another! :-) Check if the file or directory the program is expecting exists and is accessible (rw permissions).

Comment: Definitely does exist as I dragged it to the terminal to input the path and seems to have rw permissions. It works fine still for paths without spaces. Just any folder I create with spaces are broken.

Comment: What is the result of `echo "$path"` and `ls -d $(dirname "$path")`?

Comment: I get `Users/me/Desktop/a\ test/1`
`ls: /Users/me/Desktop/a\: No such file or directory`
`ls: test: No such file or directory`

Comment: Sorry, I also forgot the quotes. I meant `ls -d "$(dirname "$path")"`

Comment: Definitely no need to say sorry :-). Now I get `/Users/me/Desktop/a\ test/1` & 
`ls: /Users/me/Desktop/a\ test: No such file or directory`

Comment: Here you have the problem, the folder `/Users/me/Desktop/a test` does not exist, but you are telling the command to create a file inside. It cannot be done until the folder exists.

Comment: Definitely does exist though. If I do `ls /Users/me/Desktop/a\ test/` in terminal by copying the path directly from the output above it works fine

Comment: It does not make much sense. `ls` with the full path tells you it exists but the same full path in a quoted variable does not exists? You can see that `ls` complains about directory non-existence with the same path that itself says later the exists. :-?